# Spring/Spring Security 3.0.x execution flow

Tags: security, spring, spring-security

I'm currently in the process of migrating an application from Spring 2.5.6 to Spring 3.0.4 and Spring Security 3.0.2 and I was wondering if there was some kind of execution flow for both of these framework so that developpers could know what is being called before what.

For those of you who are doing this kind of migration, I can tell you that it's not a simple task that's why I was wondering if some experts, out there, in the wild, would have some references about these flow.

Thanks

Comment: I've done this migration but your question isn't very clear - maybe add some specifics and I can help.

Comment: I would like to have some kind of graphics of the execution flow showing what classes doing what in what order. Have you saw something like it?

Answer (score 2):

You should start here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html

This is a detailed overview of how spring works and will get you up to speed on the changes.  Additionally I highly recommend the book by [Peter Mularien - Spring Security 3](https://www.packtpub.com/spring-security-3/book).

With these two references you'll be on your way in no time.

Grant

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty familiar with the how Spring is working since I've been doing this for the last two months, but there are still some areas where I don't quite get it. The reference is a good place to start, but it's not quite complete in my eye. The book however is probably a great idea.

Comment: I've been working with Spring Security for almost a year now.  It definitely was a steep learning curve and the book helped tremendously.  We attempted some pretty wicked hard stuff and the book really broke things down.  If you have specific questions feel free to post and I'll do my best to answer.